# CrashPlan not detecting storage device

Tags: 16.04, backup, crashplan

I have installed CrashPlan on UbuntuStudio 16.04. While it launches and backs up successfully one time, upon restarting the computer there is the message "destination unavailable". The destination is an internal hard drive that does not contain the operating system. I have tried to reconnect to the drive with no success. According to CrashPlan, on Macs a file 'backup 1' (or whatever the backup name is) is created in /Volumes which must be deleted. Is Ubuntu similar? If not, any suggestions as to how to resolve this?

Comment: NB: The actual message was "Destination not accessible."

Comment: Not Ubuntu software. Seems like a question for CrashPlan support.